# java text emojis add emoji to the image

Tags: java, text, utf-8, character-encoding, emoji

I have one method of drawing the image where the text is get included in that image. Now the text contains emojis for ex: and it's not getting printed as it is in image but the rectangular box like this [].
I have used java.text. and java.awt. classes for this

```
private void drawMessageString(Graphics2D g, final int messageHeight) {
        int x = CRUSH_PADDING + CRUSH_MESSAGE_LR_PADDING;
        int y = CRUSH_PADDING + TOP_BAR_HEIGHT + CRUSH_MESSAGE_TB_PADDING;

            String myString="he new guy from New Zealand who is playing tennis   ";


            try {
                byte ptext[] = myString.getBytes("UTF-8");
                    String value;
                value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
                TextRenderer.drawString(g, value, FontUtils.getInstance().getFont(FONT_PROXIMA_NOVA, 24.0f), MSG_COLOR, new Rectangle(x, y, CRUSH_MESSAGE_WIDTH, messageHeight), TextAlignment.TOP, TextFormat.FIRST_LINE_VISIBLE);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

TextRenderer is nothing but a class created which cotains code to drawString and rectangle.

what should be the solution for this??

TextRenderer.java ==>

```
package com.text;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.LineBreakMeasurer;
import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
import java.awt.font.TextLayout;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator;
import java.text.AttributedString;

/**
 * A class which provides static methods for rendering text using alignment.
 *
 * @author  Chris Copeland
 * @version 1.0
 */
public final class TextRenderer {

    /**
     * Initialize a new instance of the {@link TextRenderer} class.
     */
    private TextRenderer() {

    }

    /**
     * Draws a string onto a <code>Graphics</code> handle, using a
     * <code>Font</code>, <code>Color</code> and target bounds to calculate the
     * location and automatic wrapping of text. The <i>align</i> property
     * determines where the text will be positioned.
     *
     * @param g A <code>Graphics</code> handle which is the target of the draw
     * operation
     * @param text  A <code>String</code> containing the text to draw
     * @param font  The <code>Font</code> to use when drawing the text
     * @param color The <code>Color</code> to use when drawing the text
     * @param bounds    A <code>Rectangle</code> representing the bounds of the
     * text
     * @return  A <code>Rectangle</code> representing the bounds consumed by the
     * text
     */
    public static Rectangle drawString(Graphics g, String text, Font font, Color color, Rectangle bounds) {
        return drawString(g, text, font, color, bounds, TextAlignment.TOP_LEFT, TextFormat.NONE);
    }

    /**
     * Draws a string onto a <code>Graphics</code> handle, using a
     * <code>Font</code>, <code>Color</code> and target bounds to calculate the
     * location and automatic wrapping of text. The <i>align</i> property
     * determines where the text will be positioned.
     *
     * @param g A <code>Graphics</code> handle which is the target of the draw
     * operation
     * @param text  A <code>String</code> containing the text to draw
     * @param font  The <code>Font</code> to use when drawing the text
     * @param color The <code>Color</code> to use when drawing the text
     * @param bounds    A <code>Rectangle</code> representing the bounds of the
     * text
     * @param align A <code>TextAlignment</code> value representing the location
     * to draw the text, relative to the <i>bounds</i>
     * @return  A <code>Rectangle</code> representing the bounds consumed by the
     * text
     */
    public static Rectangle drawString(Graphics g, String text, Font font, Color color, Rectangle bounds, TextAlignment align) {
        return drawString(g, text, font, color, bounds, align, TextFormat.NONE);
    }

    /**
     * Draws a string onto a <code>Graphics</code> handle, using a
     * <code>Font</code>, <code>Color</code> and target bounds to calculate the
     * location and automatic wrapping of text. The <i>align</i> property
     * determines where the text will be positioned.
     *
     * @param g A <code>Graphics</code> handle which is the target of the draw
     * operation
     * @param text  A <code>String</code> containing the text to draw
     * @param font  The <code>Font</code> to use when drawing the text
     * @param color The <code>Color</code> to use when drawing the text
     * @param bounds    A <code>Rectangle</code> representing the bounds of the
     * text
     * @param align A <code>TextAlignment</code> value representing the location
     * to draw the text, relative to the <i>bounds</i>
     * @param format    Additional formatting flags to use when drawing (see
     * <code>TextFormat</code> class)
     * @return  A <code>Rectangle</code> representing the bounds consumed by the
     * text
     */
    public static Rectangle drawString(Graphics g, String text, Font font, Color color, Rectangle bounds, TextAlignment align, int format) {
        if (g == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("The graphics handle cannot be null.");
        }
        if (text == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("The text cannot be null.");
        }
        if (font == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("The font cannot be null.");
        }
        if (color == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("The text color cannot be null.");
        }
        if (bounds == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("The text bounds cannot be null.");
        }
        if (align == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("The text alignment cannot be null.");
        }
        if (text.length() == 0) {
            return new Rectangle(bounds.x, bounds.y, 0, 0);
        }

        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;

        AttributedString attributedString = new AttributedString(text);
        attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, color);
        attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, font);

        AttributedCharacterIterator attributedCharIterator = attributedString.getIterator();

        FontRenderContext fontContext = new FontRenderContext(null, !TextFormat.isEnabled(format, TextFormat.NO_ANTI_ALIASING), false);
        LineBreakMeasurer lineMeasurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(attributedCharIterator, fontContext);

        Point targetLocation = new Point(bounds.x, bounds.y);
        int nextOffset = 0;

        if (align.isMiddle() || align.isBottom()) {
            if (align.isMiddle()) {
                targetLocation.y = bounds.y + (bounds.height / 2);
            }
            if (align.isBottom()) {
                targetLocation.y = bounds.y + bounds.height;
            }

            while (lineMeasurer.getPosition() < text.length()) {
                nextOffset = lineMeasurer.nextOffset(bounds.width);
                nextOffset = nextTextIndex(nextOffset, lineMeasurer.getPosition(), text);

                TextLayout textLayout = lineMeasurer.nextLayout(bounds.width, nextOffset, false);

                if (align.isMiddle()) {
                    targetLocation.y -= (textLayout.getAscent() + textLayout.getLeading() + textLayout.getDescent()) / 2;
                }
                if (align.isBottom()) {
                    targetLocation.y -= (textLayout.getAscent() + textLayout.getLeading() + textLayout.getDescent());
                }
            }

            if (TextFormat.isEnabled(format, TextFormat.FIRST_LINE_VISIBLE)) {
                targetLocation.y = Math.max(0, targetLocation.y);
            }

            lineMeasurer.setPosition(0);
        }

        if (align.isRight() || align.isCenter()) {
            targetLocation.x = bounds.x + bounds.width;
        }

        Rectangle consumedBounds = new Rectangle(targetLocation.x, targetLocation.y, 0, 0);

        while (lineMeasurer.getPosition() < text.length()) {
            nextOffset = lineMeasurer.nextOffset(bounds.width);
            nextOffset = nextTextIndex(nextOffset, lineMeasurer.getPosition(), text);

            TextLayout textLayout = lineMeasurer.nextLayout(bounds.width, nextOffset, false);
            Rectangle2D textBounds = textLayout.getBounds();

            targetLocation.y += textLayout.getAscent();
            consumedBounds.width = Math.max(consumedBounds.width, (int) textBounds.getWidth());

            switch (align) {
                case TOP_LEFT:
                case MIDDLE_LEFT:
                case BOTTOM_LEFT:
                    textLayout.draw(g2D, targetLocation.x, targetLocation.y);
                    break;

                case TOP:
                case MIDDLE:
                case BOTTOM:
                    targetLocation.x = bounds.x + (bounds.width / 2) - (int) (textBounds.getWidth() / 2);
                    consumedBounds.x = Math.min(consumedBounds.x, targetLocation.x);
                    textLayout.draw(g2D, targetLocation.x, targetLocation.y);
                    break;

                case TOP_RIGHT:
                case MIDDLE_RIGHT:
                case BOTTOM_RIGHT:
                    targetLocation.x = bounds.x + bounds.width - (int) textBounds.getWidth();
                    textLayout.draw(g2D, targetLocation.x, targetLocation.y);
                    consumedBounds.x = Math.min(consumedBounds.x, targetLocation.x);
                    break;
            }

            targetLocation.y += textLayout.getLeading() + textLayout.getDescent();
        }

        consumedBounds.height = targetLocation.y - consumedBounds.y;

        return consumedBounds;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the next maximum index of the string that will be displayed.
     *
     * @param nextOffset    The index calculated using a
     * <code>LineBreakMeasurer</code> <i>nextOffset</i> method
     * @param measurerPosition  The position within a
     * <code>LineBreakMeasurer</code>
     * @param text  The text being rendered
     * @return  The next maximum index within the string
     */
    private static int nextTextIndex(int nextOffset, int measurerPosition, String text) {
        for (int i = measurerPosition + 1; i < nextOffset; ++i) {
            if (text.charAt(i) == '\n') {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return nextOffset;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the font "Proxima Nova" contain emoji?

Comment: @RealSkeptic i searched for that but it seems they are missing in Proxima if so then what will be the best solution for this??

Comment: Well, if TextRenderer is your own class, can you show its code? And if it's not, can you point us to the specific library and version?

Comment: @RealSkeptic ok i 'll update the question

Comment: I think perhaps find a default font that contains emoji, and modify the part of the drawString method that creates an AttributedString, such that all spans of the strings that are emoji are given that font as an attribute rather than the main font.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate replies @RealSkeptic i'll try using that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the font OpenSansEmoji.ttf which is combination of 3 fonts and now its working fine for me. the image is getting generated with the text and respective emojis.

```
private void drawMessageString(Graphics2D g, final int messageHeight) {
        int x = CRUSH_PADDING + CRUSH_MESSAGE_LR_PADDING;
        int y = CRUSH_PADDING + TOP_BAR_HEIGHT + CRUSH_MESSAGE_TB_PADDING;

            String myString="he new guy from New Zealand who is playing tennis   ";


            try {
                byte ptext[] = myString.getBytes("UTF-8");
                    String value;
                value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
                TextRenderer.drawString(g, value, FontUtils.getInstance().getFont(FONT_OPEN_EMOJIFONT, 24.0f), MSG_COLOR, new Rectangle(x, y, CRUSH_MESSAGE_WIDTH, messageHeight), TextAlignment.TOP, TextFormat.FIRST_LINE_VISIBLE);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```